# How to set webpart width & height using CODE only

Tags: web-part

I know there's a way to set height & attribute of webpart by changing the settings of webpart properties. But is there anyway to set it using code?

Comment: using c# or js code?

Comment: similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74619/how-do-i-set-a-default-maximum-and-minimum-width-and-height-for-a-sharepoint-we

Comment: using only source code which is html. isit possible?